# Retornando dois objetos do repository

Tags: c#

Minha aplicação é dividida da seguinte forma:

Repository --> Faz o acesso a base de dados Progress
Controller --> Recebe o retorno do Repository e envia para View
View --> Recebe o retorno do Controller.

Seguinte, o meu Repository esta assim :

```
public Projeto.Model.Projeto ObterProjetoPorEstabCcustoCodigo(Estabelecimento pEstabelecimento, CentroCusto pCentroCusto, Projeto.Model.Projeto pProjeto)
{
    using (var pim = new PIM(new infraProgress().buscaBroker(), "", "", ""))
    {
        pim.pim_busca_projeto_codigo(pEstabelecimento.Sigla, pCentroCusto.Id, pProjeto.Id, out string resumo, out string valPrevisto, out string valAlocado, out string valVariacao, out string valSaldo, out string tipoDeDocumento, out string msg);

        var projeto = new Projeto.Model.Projeto()
        {
            Descricao = resumo,
            ValPrevisto = Convert.ToDecimal(valPrevisto),
            ValorAlocado = Convert.ToDecimal(valAlocado),
            VariacaoLimite = Convert.ToDecimal(valVariacao),
            ValorLiberadoGastar = Convert.ToDecimal(valSaldo),
            Classificacao = tipoDeDocumento
        };

        return projeto;
    }
}
```

```
public Projeto.Model.Projeto ObterProjetoPorEstabCcustoCodigo(Estabelecimento pEstabelecimento, CentroCusto pCentroCusto, Projeto.Model.Projeto pProjeto)
{
    using (var pim = new PIM(new infraProgress().buscaBroker(), "", "", ""))
    {
        pim.pim_busca_projeto_codigo(pEstabelecimento.Sigla, pCentroCusto.Id, pProjeto.Id, out string resumo, out string valPrevisto, out string valAlocado, out string valVariacao, out string valSaldo, out string tipoDeDocumento, out string msg);

        var projeto = new Projeto.Model.Projeto()
        {
            Descricao = resumo,
            ValPrevisto = Convert.ToDecimal(valPrevisto),
            ValorAlocado = Convert.ToDecimal(valAlocado),
            VariacaoLimite = Convert.ToDecimal(valVariacao),
            ValorLiberadoGastar = Convert.ToDecimal(valSaldo),
            Classificacao = tipoDeDocumento
        };

        return projeto;
    }
}
```

Repare que a procedure **pim_busca_projeto_codigo** retorna as informações do meu objeto Projeto e também um out parâmetro msg.

Esse é meu problema, eu preciso retornar o objeto  `Projeto` e também o  `msg`.

Isto porque o `msg` retorna algumas condições de erro que preciso demonstrar ao usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias formas de resolver isso. Usar tuplas poderia ser uma boa, mas acho que este mecanismo é melhor no C# 7 e acho difícil que você esteja usando esta versão da linguagem. Além disso, existe toda a questão "cultural" de usar tuplas como retorno de métodos, uma vez que muito pouco estamos acostumados a este tipo de abordagem.

A minha dica é criar uma classe *wrapper* que envolva um `Projeto` e a tal mensagem.

Algo como:

```
public class ProjetoMensagem
{
    public Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Ou, se quiser fazer uma classe genérica

```
public class ModelMensagem<T> where T : class
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

```
public ProjetoMensagem ObterProjetoPorEstabCcustoCodigo(Estabelecimento pEstabelecimento, CentroCusto pCentroCusto, Projeto.Model.Projeto pProjeto)
{
    using (var pim = new PIM(new infraProgress().buscaBroker(), "", "", ""))
    {
        pim.pim_busca_projeto_codigo(pEstabelecimento.Sigla, pCentroCusto.Id, pProjeto.Id, out string resumo, out string valPrevisto, out string valAlocado, out string valVariacao, out string valSaldo, out string tipoDeDocumento, out string msg);

        var projeto = new Projeto.Model.Projeto()
        {
            Descricao = resumo,
            ValPrevisto = Convert.ToDecimal(valPrevisto),
            ValorAlocado = Convert.ToDecimal(valAlocado),
            VariacaoLimite = Convert.ToDecimal(valVariacao),
            ValorLiberadoGastar = Convert.ToDecimal(valSaldo),
            Classificacao = tipoDeDocumento
        };

        return new ProjetoMensagem
        {
            Projeto = projeto,
            Mensagem = msg
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Gostei da sua ideia.

Comment: No caso tenho várias rotinas que passam por esse tipo de problema? Como eu posso criar algo mais genérico?

No caso, o nome da minha aplicação é PIM, poderia criar um modelo PimMensagem e dentro desse modelo ir adicionar as classes conforme as necessidades?

Comment: Depende do caso. Se você vai sempre vai ter um model e uma mensagem, pode criar uma classe genérica que contenha um objeto do genérico e uma string. Dessa forma você acaba evitando de ter que criar uma classe pra cada model.

Comment: Deixei um exemplo, @AndersonApdodeSouza

Comment: Obrigado, muito obrigado mesmo.
Problema resolvido.